# How to drive a 555 timer with pwm input?

Tags: 555

I'd like to create a square wave generator with variable frequency that is determined by the presence of a 0-5 volt input signal. I have a very sketchy understanding of electronics - but I know what an RC network is. I'm thinking that I would need to replace the resistor in the rc network with a transistor, and bias the gate such that 0-5v input would give me 0-x output frequency? The reason for the pwm input is I want to drive it with an Arduino analog out pin. The frequency range needed is 0-60khz.

Comment: Then use something like an arduino with an a/d input. Starting with a 555 vastly increases the difficulty and may well be impossible to do as you've described.

Comment: Why don't you just get the microcontroller to generate the PWM without the need for the 555?  The circuit will be a lot neater.

Comment: Thanks, I think you saved me a bunch of work. Yes, a Nano is easier and cheaper.

Comment: @HandyHowie AFAIK the PWM outputs of an arduino are largely used to vary duty cycle to effect an analog output voltage. I don't think I can get to 60khz with them. Also, the main reason for this timer is to offload some of the work as the Nano can not smoothly drive a stepper motor while parsing a serial stream.

Answer (score 3):

Often neglected on 555 examples, they have a control voltage pin. It's usually seen simply connected with a capacitor to ground, to reduce noise. However, if you apply a control voltage to it, it varies the period.

With a single 555 connected as an astable, it will vary the frequency.

With a 556 (dual 555) as an astable followed by a monostable, you can control the duty cycle at constant frequency. I use this arrangement for a stable and easy to build volts to model servo drive.

Comment: Yes, you can FM a 555 that way, but not over a 3- or 4-decade range!